# CSS Resize work for horizontal but not vertical?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a bootstrap form, trying to make it resizable both horizontally and vertically.  Using simple CSS, I have:

```
.form-group-description{
    resize: both;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 50%;

}
```

This will let me resize horizantally but not vertically.  I tried using only `resize: vertical;` but that didn't work either.

Any ideas?  You can see what I'm talking about at http://impissed.co/
I'll leave the site up until I get some help (it's the description box)

EDIT: I changed it to use textarea instead of input in the html.  But, now when you resize to the right and move back to the left, the form will stay shifted to the right.  Here's the html:

```
<div class="form-group-description form-group-lg">
    <textarea rows="4" cols="50" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Description"> </textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: The div **is** resizing...but the input inside it is not. I'd remove the fixed height of the input and make it `height:100%`...although you may need to remove the fixed height of the div.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

This appears to be a browser [bug on chrome](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=471491) - FF is fine and [IE doesn't implement css:resize](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-resize)).

You can reproduce it simply with the following code by dragging the resizer right and left.  It will resize out to the right with a fixed left position, but will try to center when shrinking down:

This happens for any resizable `textarea` with a `display:block` that is inside a `center` element.

```html
<center>
  <textarea style="display:block"></textarea>
</center>
```

[image: demo of problem]

#### Solutions

**Fix 1**: Bootstrap sets the `display` for any `.form-control` to `block`.  You'll need to rest it to `inline-block`, the text area's `initial` display.

```css
textarea.form-control {
  resize: both;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<center>
  <textarea rows="4" cols="50" type="text" 
            class="form-control" placeholder="Description">
  </textarea>
</center>
```

**Fix 2** (preferable): The [`<center`>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center) element is actually deprecated, so you *should* use the css property `text-align:center` instead.  Note that now you'll need to declare the display as inline-block to properly center it within the parent div.

```css
textarea.form-control {
  resize: both;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="text-center">
  <textarea rows="4" cols="50" type="text" 
            class="form-control" placeholder="Description">
  </textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: What does `center` have to do with this question?

Comment: @konyak, this was OPs actual issue in their linked site, which they didn't inline as a [MCVE].  It looks like their site is now broken, unfortunately per [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/1366033).  But that's why I included my own MCVE of their issue in the answer